# .net core 2 upload multiple images appended to div

Tags: asp.net, .net

So I have created a website where you can upload images.

Here's the problem:
I'm using hidden field of input type=file
And I have a designed button which trigger this input.

Now, I have a div that displays those images..

Problem is that I get only the last selected images from the user at my controller.

What happens if the user wants to upload from different directories?

I couldn't find answer after searching, Also I can't show the code right now, 
I'm using really simple code tho, 
Input of file (multiple)
Button that triggers it
Div that shows the pictures (appended with jquery)

Comment: Currently you can't upload files from different directories using only one input element. But, you could generate multiple file input elements for each directory

Comment: Assuming I will do that, how will I handle it in the server side?

Comment: Are you using ajax or a form submit?

Comment: @ZoiloReyes form submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified example:

Html:

```
<button id="inputMask">Upload Image</button>
   <div id="ImageHolder">

</div>

<form id="holder" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  let inputs = [];
  //Model binding name
  let name = "file";

  let loadImagesFromInputs = () => {
    $("#ImageHolder").empty();

    //Lets load those images
    if (!FileReader) {

      console.log("Cant load files in the navigator");
      return;
    }

    //For each input
    inputs.forEach(i => {
      //for each file in each input
      Array.from(i.files).forEach(f => {
        //prepare the file reader
        let fr = new FileReader();

        //this will run when conversion is finished
        fr.onload = function () {

          $("#ImageHolder").append($("<img>", {
            src: fr.result
          }));
        }
        //convert file to url
        fr.readAsDataURL(f);
      });
    });
  }

  $("#inputMask").click(() => {

    //Create file input
    let newInput = $("<input>", {
      type: "file",
      name: name,
      id: name,
      multiple: true,
      accept: "image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
    }).css({ width: "1", position: "absolute", opacity: "0" });

    //update the list of images on change
    newInput.change((e) => { loadImagesFromInputs() });

    //Add input to list of inputs
    inputs.push(newInput[0]);
    //Add input to form
    $("#holder").append(newInput);
    //Click input
    newInput.click();
  });



  $("#holder").submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    e.target.submit();
  })

});
```

.Net Core 2 Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MultipleFileDirectoriesDemo
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class FileController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(List<IFormFile> file)
        {
            //Do something with the list of files
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING!

Comment: Hey man, is it too much to ask about how can I delete picture after it's appended on clicking on it?

Comment: Handling specific files directly programatically is not possible on a file input for security reasons. You can clear the whole input, but that could create a problem if a user wants to delete only one image from a specific file input. Your best option is using ajax to upload the files:
1. Create an array to hold the files
2. On the file change event of your input push the file to the array
3. Create an image for the uploaded image and an event handler to delete the image from the array.
4. Handle the form submission as ajax request with the array of files

Answer (score 0):

The built in multi-file up-loaders on most browsers are pretty bad.

Consider looking at something like [jQuery.Fileuploader](https://innostudio.de/fileuploader/)

This will have the added benefit of being relatively consistent across devices and browsers.

Comment: jQuery.Fileuploader is a purely client based solution, you'll be able to keep your existing back-end (.Net Core 2) code.